# How to flatten an Array Struct to columns in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, struct, google-bigquery, pivot

Consider the table sample below  where `data` is of type `array<struct<key:string,value:string>>`, with the repeated `keys`: '**Date**', '**Country**' and '**Brand**':

| source | data.key | data.value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first_file | Date | 2022-12-14 |
|  | Country | Germany |
|  | Brand | Mercedes |
|  | Date | 2022-12-15 |
|  | Country | Germany |
|  | Brand | BMW |
| second_file | Date | 2022-12-13 |
|  | Country | Sweden |
|  | Brand | Volvo |
|  | Date | 2022-12-10 |
|  | Country | France |
|  | Brand | Renault |

By 'repeated' keys I mean that every data.key entry always consists of those keys (Date, Country, Brand). In this example, they get repeated twice per row entry, but in the real table they might get repeated even more times per unique entry. My ***desired result*** is:

| source | date | country | brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first_file | 2022-12-14 | Germany | Mercedes |
| first_file | 2022-12-15 | Germany | BMW |
| second_file | 2022-12-13 | Sweden | Volvo |
| second_file | 2022-12-10 | France | Renault |

Any help on how I can reach that result?

---

If it helps, I've managed to turn the sample table into the format below in case you'd like to try a solution to this table instead:

| source | date.key | date.value | country.key | country.value | brand.key | brand.value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first_file | Date | 2022-12-14 | Country | Germany | Brand | Mercedes |
| first_file | Date | 2022-12-15 | Country | Germany | Brand | BMW |
| second_file | Date | 2022-12-13 | Country | Sweden | Brand | Volvo |
| second_file | Date | 2022-12-10 | Country | France | Brand | Renault |

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
  tmp AS (
  SELECT
    source,
    key,
    value
  FROM
    UNNEST(ARRAY<STRUCT<source string, data ARRAY<STRUCT<key string, value string>>>>[ 
      ("first_file", [("Date","2022-12-14"), ("Country","Germany"),("Brand","Mercedes")]),
      ("second_file", [("Date","2022-12-13"), ("Country","Sweden"),("Brand","Volvo")])
      ]),
    UNNEST(data) ) -- unnest data first
SELECT
  source, date[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as date, country[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as country, brand[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] as brand, 
FROM
  tmp PIVOT (
    ARRAY_AGG(value IGNORE NULLS) FOR key IN ("Date", "Country", "Brand")) -- pivot table
```

Comment: Thanks @p13rr0m, however, the solution is hard-coded, i.e. you've put the values one by one. Would you suggest something if the number of rows (and hence column values) is unknown, i.e. if you know the keys as shown in the sample table, but not the total number of records?- imagine the table has e.g. 1 million records of similar format.

Comment: please also note I've changed the table sample

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query :

```sql
with sources AS 
(
  select 
    'first_file' as source,
    [
      struct('Date' as key, '2022-12-14' as value),
      struct('Country' as key, 'Germany' as value),
      struct('Brand' as key, 'Mercedes' as value)
    ] as data
  UNION ALL
  select 
    'second_file' as source,
    [
      struct('Date' as key, '2022-12-13' as value),
      struct('Country' as key, 'Sweden' as value),
      struct('Brand' as key, 'Volvo' as value)
    ] as data
)

select
  source,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(data) WHERE key = 'Date') AS Date,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(data) WHERE key = 'Country') AS Country,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(data) WHERE key = 'Brand') AS Brand,
from sources;
```

You can also use an `udf` to centralize the logic :

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getValue(k STRING, arr ANY TYPE) AS
((SELECT value FROM UNNEST(arr) WHERE key = k));

with sources AS 
(
  select 
    'first_file' as source,
    [
      struct('Date' as key, '2022-12-14' as value),
      struct('Country' as key, 'Germany' as value),
      struct('Brand' as key, 'Mercedes' as value)
    ] as data
  UNION ALL
  select 
    'second_file' as source,
    [
      struct('Date' as key, '2022-12-13' as value),
      struct('Country' as key, 'Sweden' as value),
      struct('Brand' as key, 'Volvo' as value)
    ] as data
)
SELECT 
  source,
  getValue('Date', data) AS Date,
  getValue('Country', data) AS Country,
  getValue('Brand', data) AS Brand
FROM sources;
```

The result is :

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mazlum Tosun, however, the solution is hard-coded, i.e. you've put the values one by one. Would you suggest something if the number of rows (and hence column values) is unknown, i.e. if you know the keys as shown in the sample table, but not the total number of records?- imagine the table has e.g. 1 million records of similar format.

Comment: please note I've changed the sample table.